# Creating buttons using WinAPI

Tags: delphi, winapi

Error data is output :

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(45): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'hButton'
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(53): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'id_Button'
[dcc32 Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(6): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'Unit1.pas'
```

Please tell us what the problem is.

My code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, Windows, Messages;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 const
  sClassName = 'MyWindow';
var
  hWnd: THandle;        // идентификатор окна (дескриптор)
  WndClass: TWndClass;  //структура WndClass
  Msg: TMsg;       //структура для принятия сообщений
  function WindowProc(hWnd: THandle; uMsg, wParam, lParam: Integer): Integer;  stdcall; export;
{функция окна}
begin
  Result := 0;
  case uMsg of
    WM_DESTROY: //если uMsg равна WM_DESTROY(код закрытия окна), то закрываемся
      begin
        halt(0);
      end;
    WM_CREATE: begin
      // создание кнопки
      hButton := CreateWindowEx (0,
        'BUTTON', // определенный класс кнопки
        '&Нажмите здесь', // надпись на кнопке
        ws_Child or ws_Visible
          or bs_PushButton, // стили для кнопки
        10, 10, // координаты левого верхнего угла
        200, 80, // размер
        hWnd, // handle родителя
        id_Button, // идентификатор кнопки (задается программистом)
        hInstance,
        nil);
      end;
    WM_COMMAND:
      // проверяем, от какой кнопки пришло сообщение
      if LoWord (wParam) = id_Button then
        // если это событие - click
        if HiWord (wParam) = bn_Clicked then
          // код обработки нажатия кнопки
          MessageBox (hWnd, 'Вы нажали на кнопку', '', MB_OK);
  end;
  Result := DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
end;

end;

end.
```

Comment: You forgot to declare the `hButton` variable. Also, you forgot to define the `id_Button` constant.

Comment: And I don't get the structure at all. Why do you have a `WindowProc` function inside your `Button1Click`?

Comment: Are you trying to build a hybrid FMX + VCL application?  If so, what do you need the FMX part for?

Answer (score 1):

The immediate reason for the compiler error is that the variables hButton and id_button are not declared in the var section.

But your code looks very odd. It looks like a Windows message processing routine (something that would fit in a low-level message handling loop) put oddly in the event handler for an existing button's OnClick.

If your real aim is just to create a new button, then try something like this (I made an event handler for the form's OnMouseUp event, but you could use something else):

```
uses
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift:
    TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  B: TButton;
begin
  B := TButton.Create(Self);
  B.Left := X;
  B.Top := Y;
  B.Width := 100;
  B.Caption := 'X = ' + IntToStr(X) + ', Y = ' + IntToStr(Y);
  B.Parent := Self;
  B.OnClick := MyButtonClickHandler;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyButtonClickHandler(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Привет!');
end;
```